# How to test and evaluate wireframes?

Tags: usability-testing, prototype, mockup, wireframe

I'm working on a web project, I did some wireframes (paper prototypes for now).

I'm thinking about some way to make user testing of my wirefrimes, is it possible to have some users feedbacks by user tests ?

Comment: Yes, you can do usability testing (we don't call it "user testing") on paper prototypes. Search in YouTube for examples. [Here's one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epEz5XPhyeQ)

Comment: You should totally test them. Tests and iteration are the key to reach a great user experience. You can do it in paper or move to digital interactive prototypes. Here you have a nice article about it: [Prototyping: Paper Versus Digital](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2017/05/prototyping-paper-versus-digital.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the approaches for creating a layout is composed by three steps:

1. Wireframe
2. Prototype
3. Mockup

So if you have realized the wireframe, a **prototype** could be the right next step, to allow user to test the product and you to take insights.

Prototypes are the better tool in the testing and documentation phase.
They are a kind of draft but realized with HTML and CSS codes, to allow the user to test with their hands the navigation experience. The pages proposed will also be similar to the final site, but will still be a prototype the must be composed of necessary content to expose the project in a comprehensive way.

An interesting source: [What Is a Prototype: A Guide to Functional UX](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/what-is-a-prototype-a-guide-to-functional-ux/)